# Configuring uWSGI to not interpret PATH_INFO

Tags: uwsgi

How can I configure uwsgi to pass in the request path unmodified as `PATH_INFO`? I.e. if there is a request `https://example.com/foo%5F/../bar?x=y`, I want `PATH_INFO` to be literally `/foo/../%5Fbar`, and not `/_bar`.

The [uWSGI documentation says](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Snippets.html#multiple-flask-apps-in-different-mountpoints) *uWSGI is able to rewrite request variables in lot of advanced ways*, but I am unable to find any way to set individual request variables, at least not without modifying the source code of uwsgi.

The reason I want to do is that I have a frontend application which takes user input and then sends a request to `http://backend.app/get/USER_INPUT`. Trouble is, there is an uwsgi in between, and when the user input is `../admin/delete-everything`, the request goes to `http://backend.app/admin/delete-everything`!
(This uwsgi change I desire will not be the only fix; the frontend app should certainly validate user input, and the backend app should not offer `/admin` to the frontend app in the first place. But as a measure of defense-in-depth, I'd like my requests to pass uwsgi unmodified.)

I am running bare uWSGI without nginx, i.e. `uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --wsgi-file myapp/wsgi.py --master --processes 8 --threads 2`.

For what it's worth, the backend app that looks into `PATH_INFO` is Django.

Comment: Please add `uwsgi` command line that you have run and also which framework you are using afterwards? Flask, Django? How does the request come to the uwsgi, through nginx or direct? Please add these details to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani Updated. I'm not sure why the app running behind uWSGI is important. I did manage to implement a workaround where I ignore uWSGI's `PATH_INFO` and recompute it from `REQUEST_URL` in the application. But this protects just one application, whereas I have many services running in such a setup.

Comment: So how are you using the `PATH_INFO` later? What I mean to say is how will changing the `PATH_INFO` help you out?

Comment: @TarunLalwani `PATH_INFO` determines which Django view will be picked. If the `PATH_INFO` is `/get/../admin` (which is what I want), it will be handled by the view for `/get`, or not match any view at all. This is safe for a request from a user who should not be able to access `/admin`.
If the `PATH_INFO` is `/admin`, it will be handled by the handler for the admin view. This is a security problem. Hopefully the admin view will be secure, i.e. require user authentication and CSRF tokens, but the attacker needs only one vulnerable view among the hundreds in my large application.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Can you elaborate how you verified that? It took some time, but I set up [a demo repository here](https://github.com/phihag/uwsgi-path-traversal-demo). If you run it (a simple `docker run phihag/uwsgi-path-traversal-demo` should suffice), you'll see that that `PATH_INFO` is the problem; as evidenced by a Django-side workaround which fixes it.

Comment: Did you see the new answer? I had launched Django with `uwsgi` only in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer holds true for the clients which do url parsing at the source. This answer is applicable, when you can actually get the correct request.

The `wsgi.py` is run by `uwsgi` and the `application` object is called as callable. This in case of `Django` is `WSGIHanlder`, which has below code

```py
class WSGIHandler(base.BaseHandler):
    request_class = WSGIRequest

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.load_middleware()

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        set_script_prefix(get_script_name(environ))
        signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__, environ=environ)
        print(environ)
        request = self.request_class(environ)
        response = self.get_response(request)

        response._handler_class = self.__class__

        status = '%d %s' % (response.status_code, response.reason_phrase)
        response_headers = [
            *response.items(),
            *(('Set-Cookie', c.output(header='')) for c in response.cookies.values()),
        ]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        if getattr(response, 'file_to_stream', None) is not None and environ.get('wsgi.file_wrapper'):
            response = environ['wsgi.file_wrapper'](response.file_to_stream)
        return response
```

I created a sample view to test the same

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index. " + request.environ['PATH_INFO'])

def index2(request, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index2. " + request.environ['PATH_INFO'])
```

and registered them using below code

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from polls.views import index2, index

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls2/', index2, name='index2'),
    path('polls2/<path:resource>', index2, name='index2'),
    path('polls/', index, name='index'),
    path('polls/<path:resource>', index, name='index'),
]
```

So what you need is overriding this class. Below is an example

```py
import django

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler


class MyWSGIHandler(WSGIHandler):
    def get_response(self, request):
        request.environ['ORIGINAL_PATH_INFO'] = request.environ['PATH_INFO']
        request.environ['PATH_INFO'] = request.environ['REQUEST_URI']

        return super(MyWSGIHandler, self).get_response(request)


def get_wsgi_application():
    """
    The public interface to Django's WSGI support. Should return a WSGI
    callable.

    Allows us to avoid making django.core.handlers.WSGIHandler public API, in
    case the internal WSGI implementation changes or moves in the future.
    """
    django.setup()
    return MyWSGIHandler()

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

After this can you can see the below results

```sh
$ curl --path-as-is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/"
Hello, world. You're at the polls index. /polls/

$ curl --path-as-is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls2/"
Hello, world. You're at the polls index2. /polls2/

$ curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls2/../polls/"
Hello, world. You're at the polls index. /polls/

$ curl --path-as-is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls2/../polls/"
Hello, world. You're at the polls index. /polls2/../polls/%
```

As you can see the change to `PATH_INFO` doesn't change which view is picked. As `polls2` still picks `index` function

After digging a bit more, I realised there is another `path` and `path_info` variable. The class for the same is picked using `path_info`

So we update our function like below

```py
class MyWSGIHandler(WSGIHandler):
    def get_response(self, request):
        request.environ['ORIGINAL_PATH_INFO'] = request.environ['PATH_INFO']
        request.environ['PATH_INFO'] = request.environ.get('REQUEST_URI', request.environ['ORIGINAL_PATH_INFO'])
        request.path = request.environ['PATH_INFO']
        request.path_info = request.environ.get('REQUEST_URI', request.environ['PATH_INFO'])
        return super(MyWSGIHandler, self).get_response(request)
```

After this change, we get the desired results

```sh
$ curl --path-as-is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls2/../polls/"
Hello, world. You're at the polls index2. /polls2/../polls/
```

Comment: This is a Django-side workaround, similar to the one [I used](https://github.com/phihag/uwsgi-path-traversal-demo/blob/master/traversaldemo/wsgi_workaround.py#L10). It works, but the problem is really uWSGI, not Django. Also, why are you overriding everything in `get_response` instead of `__call__`, as in my code?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, the idea was to handle in it in `wsgi`, whether you do it in `__call__` or `get_response` shouldn't matter as long you can make it work

Comment: Also I have checked the `uwsgi` complete source and there is nothing there to achieve the same in `uwsgi`, that you want. So you need to do use the `wsgi.py` approach only

Comment: See the code where it happens https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/3149df02ed443131c54ea6afb29fcbb0ed4d1139/core/protocol.c#L751, nothing else there to achieve what you want without the code change

Answer (score -1):

So your problem has mostly nothing to do with `uwsgi` or `Django` as such. To demonstrated the issue, I created a simple flask app with a catch all handler

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return 'You want path: %s' % path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now when you run this and make a curl request

```sh
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/tarun/../lalwani
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:5000/lalwani
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /lalwani HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 22
< Server: Werkzeug/0.15.2 Python/3.7.3
< Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 07:45:16 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
You want path: lalwani%
```

As you can see that the server never had a chance to even know we requested this. Now lets do it again and ask curl not to tamper the url

```sh
$ curl -v --path-as-is http://127.0.0.1:5000/tarun/../lalwani
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /tarun/../lalwani HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 31
< Server: Werkzeug/0.15.2 Python/3.7.3
< Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 07:48:17 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
You want path: tarun/../lalwani%
```

Now you can see that my app did receive the actual path. Now let's see the same case in a browser, with app not even running

[image: Browser]

As you can even though my service is not even running but the browser itself refactored the call to `/lalwani` instead of `/tarun/../lalwani`. So there is nothing that could have been done at your end to even correct the issue, until unless you are using a client which supports disabling the url parsing at source

Comment: (Note that the initial downvote was not from me) This answer, while carefully written out, describes the behavior of some HTTP _clients_.
It is not relevant to my question, which is about an HTTP _server_. I am getting requests for `/get/../admin` from a client which obviously did not interpret the URL. 

Also, this answer seems to miss that my goal is to enhance security: I am assuming that an attacker can append arbitrary strings onto an URL sent by the client. Sure, I'd like the client not to send me requests with `../` in the first place, but that's not how security works.

Comment: @phihag, if you are getting the `/get/../admin` in the url then i will update the answer with the original question as well, give me some time